# How to eliminate port number of tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

I have a dedicated server and I have tomcat installed on it. But the only way to access tomcat is to give the port number in the URL.
For Example: http://server.mydomain.com:8080
takes me to the tomcat server.
How can I remove the port number from the URL????

As long as I was using it, this was fine but now I have generated a SOAP service and I have deployed it on axis2. Now the URL to access my service is like  http://server.mydomain.com:8080/axis2/services/MyService?wsdl
which shows the port number, so how can I remove this port number??

OR is there any other way to make my service accessible without showing the port number??
Thanks

Comment: You read [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) and modify the configuration to use the port you want (for instance, port 80, the default HTTP port).

Answer (score 4):

3 words: **Apache Reverse Proxy**

I hate dealing with Java/Tomcat idiosyncrasies like this so what I do is I reverse proxy through Apache to give Tomcat a nice/normal port 80 URL.  I have a detailed answer on my approach [here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/473130/securing-apache-solr-in-production/473307#473307).

That way my Tomcat setup is sane & clean & Apache allows me more flexibility in front-end accessibility & control.

Answer (score 3):

Not showing the port number means that it must run on port 80 (http) or 443 (https). For that you need to modify your tomcat configuration. I found this on the internet and hope it helps: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/